# windows hosts: how can I redirect HTTPS site?

Tags: windows, https, hosts

I have that in my host

```
127.0.0.1 block.opendns.com
```

It works when I use: 
http://block.opendns.com

But does not work when I use:
https://block.opendns.com

Any idea how to use hosts with an HTTPS site ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not work" / "works"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP and HTTPS are only the protocol/port which is being used for your request. Adding this line to your host file "127.0.0.1 block.opendns.com" will only tell your PC that block.opendns.com is located at this IP 127.0.0.1 so no matter what you put before the URL (http/https) it will resolve 127.0.0.1.